# How to query run raw select query in Blazor over ASE database

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I would like to use Blazor to make some reports from existing Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise. The issue is that i remember only few table names. I dont remember how many columns they have or what datatype is stored in specific column so i cannot create a model. My idea to solve it was to create a Blazor page with rich text box and result table which would allow to run query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Plants where 0=1
```

to result column names only. Basing on that information i could create the models to follow actions described widely as best practices.

After watching over 20 hours of tutorials on udemy, youtube, etc and similar time on microsoft, dapper, insight tutorials I was not able to reach my goal.

I have my connection string in appsetings.json

```
"ASEdbContext": "Data Source=myServer;Port=5000;Database=myDatabase;Uid=myUser;Pwd=myPass;"
```

Is it possible to just create a service class to put data from database to c# dataset/table/list and then use the dataset/table/list on razor component display it on a table?